# Print the NSTableView's row number of the row clicked by the user

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I have a `NSTableView` with one column. I would like to print the row number of the row that the user has clicked on. I am not sure where I should start with this. Is there a method for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `selectedRowIndexes` property from the tableView in the `tableViewSelectionDidChange` method in your NSTableView delegate.

In this example, the tableView allows multiple selection.

**Swift 3**

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let myTable = notification.object as? NSTableView {
        // we create an [Int] array from the index set
        let selected = myTable.selectedRowIndexes.map { Int($0) }
        print(selected)
    }
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    var mySelectedRows = [Int]()
    let myTableViewFromNotification = notification.object as! NSTableView
    let indexes = myTableViewFromNotification.selectedRowIndexes
    // we iterate over the indexes using `.indexGreaterThanIndex`
    var index = indexes.firstIndex
    while index != NSNotFound {
        mySelectedRows.append(index)
        index = indexes.indexGreaterThanIndex(index)
    }
    print(mySelectedRows)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-selectedRowIndexes`

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTableView/selectedRowIndexes

Then you can use those indexes to grab the data from your `dataSource`
(typically an array)