# macOS fatal error: Index out of range NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, uitableview, nstableview, nsindexpath

I am developing a macOS application. i have a problem with a tableView that load an array of products from a web server. The products are correctly received by the app (i see them in console). But i have these problems:
1) i can't see my products text descriptions in my tableView cells;
2) when i click on a single cell the app crash with this error message:

```
 fatal error: Index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```
import Cocoa
import AppKit


class Controller: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet var tableViewa: NSTableView!
var products = [Product]()   

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Table list"

    tableViewa.reloadData()
   } 

override func viewDidAppear() {
    reload()
    tableViewa.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
    tableViewa.allowsEmptySelection = true
    tableViewa.gridColor = NSColor.red

}
func reload() {
    products = []
    tableViewa.reloadData()
    tableViewa.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
   Products.store.requestProducts{success, products in
        if success {
            self.products = products!

            self.tableViewa.reloadData()

        }else {
            print("download failed")
        }
        self.tableViewa.reloadData()   
    }
}


extension MasterViewController: NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

func numberOfRows(in atableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    print("products number: \(products.count)")
 return products.count
}

func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        let tas = IndexPath(item: products.count, section: 0)
        let Cell = tableViewa.makeView(withIdentifier:  NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Cell"),owner: tas ) as! ProductCell

        let product = products[(tas as NSIndexPath).item]//here crash my app
        Cell.product = product
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  -> NSTableCellView{
    let Cell = tableViewa.makeView(withIdentifier:  NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Cell"),owner: indexPath ) as! ProCell
    let product = products[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]
     Cell.product = product
     Cell.textField?.stringValue = array.item.1

    return Cell


}

}
```

Comment: `let tas = IndexPath(item: products.count, section: 0)` and `let product = products[(tas as NSIndexPath).item]`. Let's say that products has ONE item. then `products.count` returns `1`. So `let product = products[(tas as NSIndexPath).item]` becomes `let product = products[1]`. But the item is at index `0`, not one, so you'll get an out of range.

Comment: so how can i avoid this error?

Comment: See there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29200067/1801544 Your `tas` is `selected`.

Comment: this no works for me...because if i declare let product = products[(selected as NSIndexPath).row] Xcode gives me this error: Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to type 'NSIndexPath' in coercion

Comment: Nobody knows what ProductCell is.

Comment: `let product = products[selected]` instead?

Comment: I tried...if i declare let product = products[selected] Xcode gives me this error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[SKProduct]' with an index of type '[Int]'

Comment: I'm totally confused. ***NS**TableView* doesn't know sections in `(NS)IndexPath` and there is no method `cellForRowAt` in `NSTableViewDataSource`. Are you really talking about macOS? And – like iOS – **never** use `makeView(withIdentifier` outside of `viewForColumn:row`

Answer (score 2):

How ya doing?

You can use the IndexPath init

```
init(row: Int, section: Int)
```

instead

```
init(item: Int, section: Int)
```

After that you recover the row that way

```
let product = products[(tas as NSIndexPath).row]
```

Explanation:

The *item* parameter is used to identify an item in a section from *collection view* and row to table view

Comment: Thank you for the help, but i get this error: Value of type 'NSIndexPath' has no member 'row'

Comment: Very weird. Take a look on this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsindexpath

Comment: i see. Could be i declared in a bad way the init? I made this:extension NSIndexPath {
    init(row: Int, section: Int) {
        self.init(row: 1, section: 0)
    }
    
}

Comment: i tried in different ways but i get ever the same error:     "Value of type 'NSIndexPath' has no member 'row'"

Comment: Are you accessing like this (tas as NSIndexPath).row?

Try with IndexPath instead NSIndexPath

Comment: i tried now...i get the same error "Value of type 'IndexPath' has no member 'row'"

Comment: Hey I can see whats is wrong on your code. In this line `let tas = IndexPath(item: products.count, section: 0)` you pass the `products.count` but the count always will greater than you products index. Did you get it?

Comment: and so i should write item: products.count - 1?

Comment: You can do this it will work! But I don't know what do you want for your logic

Comment: Fantastic! the problem was just that missing "-1" now my app doesn't crash if i select a row.